# React google login stay signed in even after closing all tabs

Tags: reactjs, google-signin, react-google-login

I'm using https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login for auth in my React app. Everything's working except when I close all my tabs and return to my site (within seconds, not even that long), I have to sign in again... How can I persist the login for some amount of time?

Here's my current setup:

```
<GoogleLogin
    clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}
    buttonText='Continue with Google'
    onSuccess={handleGoogleOAuthResponse}
    onFailure={handleError}
    isSignedIn={true}
    prompt='consent'
    accessType='offline'
    redirectUri={process.env.REACT_APP_FRONT_END_BASE_URL}
/>

const handleGoogleOAuthResponse = ({ accessToken, profileObj }) => {
    postRequest('rest-auth/google/', null, { 'access_token': accessToken }) // backend in Django
    .then(({ access_token, refresh_token, user }) => {
        setAccessToken(access_token); // these are just local states
        setRefreshToken(refresh_token);
        setProfile(profileObj);
        setError(null);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        setError(error);
    });
};

const handleError = (error, details) => {
    setError(`${error}: ${details}`);
}
```

Comment: I would suppose that the issue is not within this snippet, rather in your `handleGoogleOAuthResponse` handler. Could you provide that part as well?

Comment: Also, I see you are using `redirectUri` but without `uxMode='redirect'`. Could that be part of the issue?

Comment: Updated -- putting `uxMode='redirect'` breaks the whole thing in Safari for some reasons... But I don't think it has anything to do with this? Right now I'm only getting the access token back and set it in my state. Is that why?

Comment: Local state is only good for the lifespan of a component, and you want longer than the lifespan of a browser session. You need a more persistent way of storing tokens like Local Storage, IndexedDB, or Cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is using just the ephemeral state, which gets lost on page reload (and even every time component unmounts) as it is in-memory only. One quick solution would be to also store your token in a `localStorage`:

```
    .then(({ access_token, refresh_token, user }) => {
        setAccessToken(access_token); // these are just local states
        setRefreshToken(refresh_token);
        setProfile(profileObj);
        setError(null);

        // in addition to existing code above, add this part to persist the tokens
        localStorage.setItem('accessTokenKey', access_token);
        localStorage.setItem('refreshTokenKey', refresh_token);
    })
```

With tokens stored, we need to load them as well upon next start of the app, which can be done like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const access_token = localStorage.getItem('accessTokenKey');
    const refresh_token = localStorage.setItem('refreshTokenKey');
    setAccessToken(access_token);
    setRefreshToken(refresh_token);
}, []);
```

or used as initial state in the `useState` hooks:

```
const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('refreshTokenKey'));
const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('accessTokenKey'));
```